# DrRacket removing element starting from the end of the list

Tags: scheme, racket

I have the code which is removing the first appearance of the element

```
(define delete
  (lambda (a lst)
    (cond
      ((null? lst) (lst))
      ((eq? (car lst) a) (cdr lst))
      (else (cons (car lst)
                  (delete a (cdr lst)))))))
```

Now, I want it to remove element but starting from the end of the list so for example `(delete 2 '(2 5 4 2 6))` will return `'(2 5 4 6)`
I don't know how to do this so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for a `foldr`:

```
(define (remove-from-end v xs)
   (let ((flag #t))
     (foldr (lambda (x r)
               (if (and flag (equal? v x)) 
                     (begin (set! flag #f) 
                            r)
                     (cons x r)))
            '() xs)))
```

Testing:

```
> (remove-from-end 2 '(2 5 4 2 6))
'(2 5 4 6)
```

Comment: ... though to do with without faking multiple return values, you're probably going to want CPS. I'm sticking with double reverse; same big-o running time.

Comment: big-O is a canard. :) /joking/ lots of 2x or 3x slower stuff has the same big-O. also, well-encapsulated mutation, what's wrong with that, really? of course the other option is a sum type for the foldr's result, switching "mid-flight" from one variant to the other... but that expresses exactly the switching of a flag's value, isn't it. If we don't want mutation at all, let's forbid it in the language! until then... they have it even in Haskell.

Comment: double reverse is good and nice - as an executable specification. of course for the really performance-concerned applications *lists* as a whole might just be the wrong option altogether, and then clarity and brevity wins big. :) but mental gymnastics are not entirely without purpose either. the main thing is, having fun!

Answer (score 3):

Sure, no problem:

```
#lang racket

(define (delete-last a lst) 
   (reverse (delete a (reverse lst))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't use mutation or multiple loops. It's probably something similar to what JohnClements was alluding to in one of his comments.

These characteristics don't make it better or worse than the other solutions. Each implementation involves a trade off and it's good to think about those and just be aware of them

```
(define (delete-last a lst)
  (define (loop lst return)
    (if (null? lst)
        (return null #t)
        (loop (cdr lst)
              (lambda (rest untouched?)
                (if (and untouched? (eq? a (car lst)))
                    (return rest #f)
                    (return (cons (car lst) rest) untouched?))))))
  (loop lst (lambda (result _) result)))

(delete-last 'a '(a b c a d e f g a h i a j k l))
;; '(a b c a d e f g a h i j k l)
```

Comment: well, yes, two traversals just like in my version, while John's does it in three. though  it can also be done in one (with the mutation of "the worst" kind, the list structure mutation).